# What is the equivalent command of "minikube start --memory 5120 --cpus=4" for "Kind"?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, cassandra, resource-management, kind

Here in [Cassandra deployment instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/), it says:

> Caution:
>
> Minikube defaults to 2048MB of memory and 2 CPU. Running Minikube with
> the default resource configuration results in insufficient resource
> errors during this tutorial. To avoid these errors, start Minikube
> with the following settings:
>
> minikube start --memory 5120 --cpus=4

But I don't know what is the equivalent command if I use `Kind` instead of `minikube`?

I also like to know if I want to set these settings permanently for my `Kind` cluster, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There is no equivalent in kind to achieve what you want. However, kind does not enforce any memory/cpu constraint by default, so unless you really want to do that, you can skip below explanation.

There is no equivalent command for kind to enforce cpu/memory limits as it is done by minikube.

This said, minikube enforces resource limits by limiting the amount of resources of the minikube docker container (by default it limits to 25% memory usage, and 2 CPUs).

You can verify this limitation doing the following:

```
# docker inspect minikube --format="{{ .HostConfig.NanoCpus }}"
2000000000 # means 2 CPUs
# docker inspect minikube --format="{{ .HostConfig.Memory }}"
16672358400 # 16GB of RAM, ran on a host with 64GB of RAM
```

On the contrary, kind does not enforce any limitation on the deployed docker containers. You can verify it by running above commands on the Docker containers deployed by kind.

With some (overkill) reverse engineering you can figure out the docker run command used by kind to spawn the containers:

```
# docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro assaflavie/runlike kind-worker
docker run --name=kind-worker --hostname=kind-worker --env=container=docker --env=KIND_EXPERIMENTAL_CONTAINERD_SNAPSHOTTER --env=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin --volume=/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --volume=/var --network=kind --privileged --workdir=/ --restart=on-failure:1 --label='io.x-k8s.kind.role=worker' --label='io.x-k8s.kind.cluster=kind' --runtime=runc --detach=true -t kindest/node:v1.25.3@sha256:f52781bc0d7a19fb6c405c2af83abfeb311f130707a0e219175677e366cc45d1
```

Therefore you can re-run the kind worker container setting up whatever cpu/memory limitation you may want. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Answer (score 1):

Kind is a tool designed to create local test and CI environments for kubernetes. This uses docker and kubeadm as a backend. Since its development is still in progress, kind also supports docker and kubectl commands for cluster management and if you are trying to set any memory value or want to change default memory limit for your docker containers it can be done using [docker commands](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) and [kubectl commands](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/admin/limitrange/). Kind currently has native controls over networking and load balancing alone(as these are the only details available in official [documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)).